# OpenCv c++; How to segment a video into clips of size N

Tags: c++, opencv, video

I have a video that I need to partition into small clips of size N, N being somewhere between 3 and 10 frames. Is there a function or method that will grab the next N frames and return them in a vector/array?

Comment: See the answer [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/6580/cutting-selected-frame-ranges-from-a-video/#6582) might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to split a video into small clips:

```
vector<vector<Mat>> frames; // result store here, each one is a clip 
                            // (each contains num_frame_in_a_slice frames)
int num_frame_in_a_slice = 5; // set the number you want here

VideoCapture capture;
capture.open("your-video-path");

int track = 0;
vector<Mat> temp;
while(1)
{
    Mat frame;
    capture >> frame;

    if (!frame.empty())
    {
        if (track < num_frame_in_a_slice)
        {
            temp.push_back(frame);
            track++;
        }
        else
        {
            frames.push_back(temp);
            temp.clear();
            track = 0; // reset
        }
    }
}
```